# Is there a way to export SVG files from Adobe XD without id's?

Tags: html, svg, adobe, xml-namespaces, adobe-xd

When exporting (for example) icons from Adobe XD as SVG files, the code contains ID's that are for me unnecessary. When I want to use the SVG files for instance inline in an HTML file, it will give ID duplications. I can get rid of the ID's manually, but I would like to know if there is a way to remove the ID's before exporting from XD?

E.g.:

```
<clipPath id="a"><clipPath id="c"><g id="b" clip-path="url(#c)"><g clip-path="url(#a)">
```

When you use more than two svg files, you have ID duplications:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="84" height="84" viewBox="0 0 84 84"><defs><clipPath id="a"><rect width="47.5"
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="84" height="84" viewBox="0 0 84 84"><defs><clipPath id="a"><rect width="47.203"
```

The export settings I use (tried also the other options, without result):

[image: export settings]

I could not find this topic on the Adobe XD forums.

Comment: you may try to ask your question here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=adobe+xd

Comment: Another option is to remove the IDs with the [SVGO](https://github.com/svg/svgo) library/[SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) online tool. Caution: this changes the file **a lot** by default. Best strategy is to turn of everything and then to activate what optimization you need.